# Logging into websites or applications

Tags: javascript, java, logging

I have one doubt. Many websites and application we see that once the user is logged in, and opens the same url in a new tab, the user is still logged in. If the window is closed and the user opens a new browser then the user is not logged in. Apart from cookies how this is handled by the sites and applications.

Also please suggest apart from backend, how it can be handled at client side as well.

Thanks in advance,
Megha

Comment: Why do you say ***"apart from cookies"***?  The behavior you see IS because of cookies.  Cookies are stored in the local browser so they apply to any tab or window you open within that browser on that site, but apply to no windows you open in another browser.  Cookies may be specified to be session cookies only (only saved until the browser is closed or may be given a specific expiration date in the future and will persist even if the browser is closed),

Answer (score 0):

we create one session per browser now matter how many tabs you have opened in the same all will share the same session but when you open the new instance of browser it will create the new session.

when we send the request to web browser we sent some information with session which can be accessed at the server side.

i am giving the example in java.

ex.

**index.html**

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="welcome.jsp">  
<input type="text" name="uname">  
<input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<html>  
<body>  
<%   

String name=request.getParameter("uname");  
out.print("Welcome "+name);  

session.setAttribute("user",name);  

<a href="second.jsp">second jsp page</a>  

%>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**second.jsp**

```
<html>  
<body>  
<%   

String name=(String)session.getAttribute("user");  
out.print("Hello "+name);  

%>  
</body>  
</html>
```

in the `welcome.jsp` we are setting the value of attribute *user* in session.

`welcome.jsp` will create the new instance of the session with every request of browser.

in the `second.jsp` we are getting the value of attribute *user* from session.

now in `second.jsp` we can check that we are having the *user* attribute attached with in it or not accordingly we can redirect to the next page.